# Why shouldn't I use sizeof(double) in C files

Tags: c, sizeof

My professor told me not to use **sizeof(double)** when reading/writing into a binary file. Now, he told me the reason, but I forgot it. Example:

```
double grade;

fread(grade, sizeof(double), 1, fp) != 1
```

But, instead:

```
fread(grade, 4, 1, fp) != 1
```

Now, the trick is that the double could be 4 or 8 bytes, so what does one do in this situation?

Comment: IMO the first one is system independent but the second one is not

Comment: The first parameter of `fread` is a pointer.

Comment: I guess you meant `fread(&grade...` - and I cannot think why he would say that

Comment: If you are reading and writing from different platforms, then neither is guaranteed to work.

Comment: It depends entirely on how the file/stream format is specified. However, since the exponent sizes of `binary32` FP numbers and `binary64` FP numbers (the most common 4/8 octet floating point formats) are different (what you'd be reading in BE systems; endianity is not standarised either), this code is **probably wrong**.

Comment: If Prof is suggesting `fread(grade, 4, 1, fp) != 1`,  Smile and nod and look forward to your next class.  I would not hire the Prof.

Comment: 'what does one do in this situation?' - don't use flat binary files.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `sizeof(grade)`, because if you change the variable type, this line works still fine. Perhaps he would say that ?

```
fread(&grade, sizeof(grade), 1, fp)
```

But I see no reason to write the value directly, because it may not work on another system.